# Долгая обработка массива Numpy

Tags: python, производительность, numpy

Обработка массива из 787456 элементов идёт около 15 секунд.Почему так долго? Каких то особо сложных вычислений в цикле не происходит.Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

```
import numpy
width=1024
height=769
dt1=numpy.dtype([('w', numpy.float), ('a',numpy.int32),('b',numpy.int32)])
edges=numpy.zeros(width*height*4,dtype=dt1)
num=1
for y in range(0,height):
    for x in range(0,width):
        if x<(width-1):
            edges[num]['a']=1
            edges[num]['b']=1
            edges[num]['w']=1   
            num+=1
        if y<(height-1):
            edges[num]['a']=2
            edges[num]['b']=2
            edges[num]['w']=2
            num+=1
        if ((x<width-1) and (y<height-1)):
            edges[num]['a']=3
            edges[num]['b']=3
            edges[num]['w']=3
            num+=1
        if ((x<width-1) and (y>0)):
            edges[num]['a']=4
            edges[num]['b']=4
            edges[num]['w']=4
            num+=1
```

Вот код на с++ который я пытаюсь переписать на python

```
static inline float diff(image<float> *r, image<float> *g, image<float> *b,
             int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
  return sqrt(square(imRef(r, x1, y1)-imRef(r, x2, y2)) +
          square(imRef(g, x1, y1)-imRef(g, x2, y2)) +
          square(imRef(b, x1, y1)-imRef(b, x2, y2)));
}
// build graph
  edge *edges = new edge[width*height*4];
  int num = 0;
  for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {

      if (x < width-1) {
    edges[num].a = y * width + x;
    edges[num].b = y * width + (x+1);
    edges[num].w = diff(smooth_r, smooth_g, smooth_b, x, y, x+1, y);
    num++;
      }

      if (y < height-1) {
    edges[num].a = y * width + x;
    edges[num].b = (y+1) * width + x;
    edges[num].w = diff(smooth_r, smooth_g, smooth_b, x, y, x, y+1);
    num++;
      }

      if ((x < width-1) && (y < height-1)) {
    edges[num].a = y * width + x;
    edges[num].b = (y+1) * width + (x+1);
    edges[num].w = diff(smooth_r, smooth_g, smooth_b, x, y, x+1, y+1);
    num++;
      }

      if ((x < width-1) && (y > 0)) {
    edges[num].a = y * width + x;
    edges[num].b = (y-1) * width + (x+1);
    edges[num].w = diff(smooth_r, smooth_g, smooth_b, x, y, x+1, y-1);
    num++;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: можете объяснить что вы пытаетесь сделать? что такое `w`, `a`, `b`?

Comment: Пытаюсь инициализировать веса рёбер графа.a- первая вершина ребра,b- вторая вершина ребра,w-вес ребра. Нужно для алгоритма сегментации изображений По хорошему значения a,b и w должны вычисляться, но  для тестирования производительности я записываю в них константы.

Comment: почему бы не воспользоваться обычным 3D массивом или, если действительно нужно индексирование по имени - pandas.DataFrame?

Comment: Понял,попробую вариант с 3d массивом

Comment: Главная проблема в том, что вы совершенно не пользуетесь преимуществами Numpy... Было бы проще если бы вы полностью изложили задачу или дали фопмулы расчета `a`,`b`,`w`

Comment: Добавил в вопрос код для вычисления,a,b,w

Comment: вы используете классический for, если хотите ускорите попробуйте map или итераторы в numpy

Comment: я не понимаю логики вашего C++ кода, поэтому не могу посоветовать конкретного векторизированного Numpy решения. Могу посоветовать воспользоваться модулем Numba для значительного ускорения циклов. [Пример ускорения в 3000 раз...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50972089/5741205)